# Do we have any alternative method `ecdsa.ExportECPrivateKey` which is in .Net Preview(3.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate2

I am using below method to get private PEM file

`ExportECPrivateKey` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.exportecprivatekey?view=netcore-3.0) - this method is in preview state With this method I could able to solve the issue I am looking for some other way in .Net core 2.2 to solve this

When I try to publish with this method in preview which is in .Net core 3.0
in Azure function I am facing issue saying this method is not available

Error and call stack:
Method not found:
`` Byte[] System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.ExportECPrivateKey()'.   at CertGen.CertificateUtil.CreateAndSignCertificate(String subjectName, X509Certificate2 signingCertificate, Action`1 log)
   at CertGen.CreateDeviceCert.GenerateDeviceCert(String SubjectName, String NewCertPassword, Byte[] SigningCertPfxFile, String SigningCertPassword, Action`1 log) in E:\AlsterGSD\Rohit\src\CertGen\CreateDeviceCert.cs:line 27 ``

Comment: Can you show us some of the code or error/stack traces?

Comment: .Net Core 2.2 is no longer in preview and does include  `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.ECDsa`. Then, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `ExportECPrivateKey` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.exportecprivatekey?view=netcore-3.0) - this method is in preview state
With this method I could able to solve the issue

I am looking for some other way in .Net core 2.2 to solve this

Please let me know If I am not clear

Comment: @Stef Geysels

Please find the call stack when I run azure function with .Net core 3.0  

`Method not found: 'Byte[] System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.ExportECPrivateKey()'.   at CertGen.CertificateUtil.CreateAndSignCertificate(String subjectName, X509Certificate2 signingCertificate, Action`1 log)
   at CertGen.CreateDeviceCert.GenerateDeviceCert(String SubjectName, String NewCertPassword, Byte[] SigningCertPfxFile, String SigningCertPassword, Action`1 log) in E:\AlsterGSD\Rohit\src\CertGen\CreateDeviceCert.cs:line 27`

Comment: @MadhuSameena Can you update your question (via Edit)? This way your question will improve in quality and attract more people to try provide it with an answer.

Comment: Maybe just use the built in `CertificateRequest` class if you're trying to build certificates, and then eliminate the need for the method altogether?

Comment: @bartonjs If it is possible to share some code or links to generate certificates along with public and private PEM files  - That ill be great
I am new to these certificate concepts.